# Migrated from Exchange 2003 to Exchange 2007 - remove old 03 computer account?

Tags: exchange-2007, exchange-2003, accounts

Migrated from Exchange 2003 to 2007 back in February of this year.

I've still got the old exchange computer account in AD.

***Can I simply delete the computer account or will bad things start happening?***

I've looked in the Exchange 07 console and don't see the old server listed at all.

HOWEVER: we do still have an old CNAME for this old Exchange server pointing to the new one for a few old clients that still have their mail server set to the old name...if that matters at all.

I ran "get-exchangeserver" on the new server and the old one isn't listed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was Exchange 2003 properly uninstalled from the old server?

If the server is still active and running Exchange, you need to uninstall Exchange before removing it.

If it's active but not running Exchange anymore, you can remove it from the domain (if it doesn't have anything else on it)

If it was simply turned off without first uninstalling Exchange, then you have a problem...

Comment: It was properly uninstalled from the old server and is turned off.

Comment: You can safely delete the account from AD, then.